# how to improve the rails code of update multiple attributes in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, module, metaprogramming, ruby-on-rails-6

I need to update the values of many attributes of a table in rails . I am using inline-edit for that. Please see the below code and give me suggestions to improve the code in a better way(modularization,meta-programming...).

**products_controller.rb**

```
def update
  @page=params[:page] # In normal update no such param, so initialized with nil. If inline edit, that will be "inline"     
  @page=="inline"? inline_update: update_by_app_params    
end


#Method to update by inline Update of individual params
def inline_update    
  if inline_edit_param_contains_description?
     status = Product.update_description(params,current_user.id,@product)
  elsif inline_edit_param_contains_order_number?
     status = Product.update_order_number(params,current_user.id,@product)            
  elsif inline_edit_param_contains_date?
     status = Product.update_end_date(params,current_user.id,@product)
  ..........................
  ..........................
  end      
  (status==true)? respond_block : rescue_block 
end


def respond_block
  respond_to do |format|         
    format.json { render json: {status: true, description: @product.description} } if inline_edit_param_contains_description?
    format.json { render json: {status: true, order_number: @product.order_number} } if inline_edit_param_contains_order_number?
    ...........................
    ...........................
end

def rescue_block    
  flash.now[:error] = @product.errors.full_messages.uniq.join(', ')    
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { respond_with_bip(@product) }      
  end
end


 #Method to check description in inline edit
def inline_edit_param_contains_description?    
  params[:product][:description]
end

#Method to check order number in inline edit
def inline_edit_param_contains_order_number?    
  params[:product][:order_number]
end

..............
..............
```

**product.rb**

```
#This method will update the description of product
def self.update_description params,user_id,product    
  product.order=product.request_no   
  status = product.update(:description=>params[:product][:description],:last_modified_by=>user_id)
  ProductHistory.update_history product, 'updated' if(status==true)   
  status
 end


#This method will update the order_number of product
def self.update_order_number params,user_id,product    
  product.order=product.request_no   
  status = product.update(:order_number=>params[:product][:order_number],:last_modified_by=>user_id)
  ProductHistory.update_history product, 'updated' if(status==true)   
  status
 end

.................
.................
```

Please help to improve the code.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just do: `@product.update(product_params)` according to the standard CRUD operation. Rails is smart enough to understand that just one attribute has been changed and will adjust its `UPDATE` statement accordingly.

You can check this in the server log if you want to.

Then, my suggestion woud be to pass back the changed fields by using the `changed_attributes` option and handle this entire JSON object client side (since it only contains the changed values you can process them all):

```
class ProductController < ApplicationController
  ...

  def update
    product.update(product_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: product.changed_attributes }
    end
  end

  private

  def product
    @product ||= current_user.products.find(params[:id])
  end

  def product_params
    params.require(:product).permit(:name, :description, :order_number, ...)
  end
end
```